# Is "Say what is you try" correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order, questions, possessives

> A: I will try to... 
> B: Say **what is you try**!

I think it should be **Say what is your try!**
Do native speakers say like that? Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It can be:

Say,

> "what are you trying to..."
>   or
>   "what will you try (to)..."

Although the second sounds weird to me, it may be incorrect.

It can also be:

Say,

> "what is it you're trying to..."
>   or
>   "what is it you try to..."

These are questions, I think they are more natural like this.

> "Say, what is it you're trying to accomplish here?"

To get imperative you switch the positions of the pronoun and the verb. "you are", "you will" and "it is".